# Reverse datetime (POSIXct data) axis in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to create a plot of POSIXct times using ggplot, and would like to reverse the axis, but am struggling to make it work.
I've been using `scale_y_datetime`, because in my real application, it's important that I have control of the breaks on this axis.

Here's an example of my problem, first with normal ordering, and then my attempt to reverse the axis.

```
# Some random dates and values to plot
MyData <-
  structure(list(Date = structure(c(1492979809.99827, 1492602845.68722, 
  1493093428.90318, 1492605578.0691, 1492961342.65056, 1492771976.83545, 
  1493020588.88485, 1493057018.85104, 1492852011.23873, 1492855996.55059
  ), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), Value = c(4.52885504579172, 
  6.0024610790424, 8.96430060034618, 7.06435370026156, 5.08460514713079, 
  3.47828012891114, 6.29844291834161, 0.898315710946918, 1.44857675535604, 
  5.74641009094194)), .Names = c("Date", "Value"), row.names = c(NA, 
  -10L), class = "data.frame")

library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
ggplot(MyData, aes(x=Value, y=Date)) +
  geom_point() + 
  scale_y_datetime(limits=c(min(MyData$Date),max(MyData$Date)))
```

which produces this:
[image: DateTime MinMax Limits]

If I attempt to reverse the Y axis, by reversing limits, I lose all breaks and data, like this:

```
ggplot(MyData, aes(x=Value, y=Date)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_datetime(limits=c(max(MyData$Date),min(MyData$Date)))
```

[image: DateTime MaxMin Limits]

Is there a simple way to reverse the datetime axis?

Comment: I'd question whether this is an appropriate visualization. Dates are usually independent variables and so (1) most people would expect to see them on the x-axis and (2) in that case, reversal would not make sense. Perhaps you could reverse by converting to "time since most recent date", _e.g._ `max(Date) - Date` ?

Comment: @neilfws I don't disagree with you. My example was just to illustrate the problem that I was having, and isn't exactly what I'm trying to achieve. My ultimate goal is to generate something which is more of a calendar style output, where I have Weeks on the Y axis, and days along the X axis. As when looking at a calendar, it makes more sense to show weeks progressing from top-to-bottom. Thanks!

Comment: In that case I'd do a search for "ggplot2 calendar", sure to be a problem that others have thought about and addressed.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

With the help from this [post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ggplot2/qrcvqy6TdzI) from Hadley Wickham here is how you can get a reverse datetime scale:

```
library(scales)
c_trans <- function(a, b, breaks = b$breaks, format = b$format) {
  a <- as.trans(a)
  b <- as.trans(b)
  
  name <- paste(a$name, b$name, sep = "-")
  
  trans <- function(x) a$trans(b$trans(x))
  inv <- function(x) b$inverse(a$inverse(x))
  
  trans_new(name, trans, inverse = inv, breaks = breaks, format=format)

}

rev_date <- c_trans("reverse", "time")

ggplot(MyData, aes(x=Value, y=Date)) +
  geom_point() + 
  scale_y_continuous(trans = rev_date)
```

Here is the plot:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the link and the answer. This is working perfectly!

Comment: @Marcelo seems like this method no longer works as of ggplot2 version 3.0.0. Looks like the `trans_new()` arguments are in the wrong order and `format` gets passed as `minor_breaks`; explicitly naming the argument should fix it.

Comment: I get: `Error in as.trans(a) : could not find function "as.trans"`

Comment: @profPlum "as.trans" comes from the scales package.

Comment: you have to load the scales package

Comment: This doesn't work anymore. 
`Error: Invalid input: time_trans works with objects of class POSIXct only`. Any idea how to fix?

Comment: Since scales version >= 1.2.0, the 'domain' that you provide to `time_trans` has to be of POSIXct class (https://github.com/r-lib/scales/releases). `trans_new` gives by default domains of class numeric (`c(-Inf, Inf)`), which will trigger the error when using scales >= 1.2.0. So the solution is to add to `trans_new` the option `domain = c(as.POSIXct(-Inf), as.POSIXct(Inf))`. I suggested this as an edit to this answer but apparently this "makes no sense"... Would be nice if someone with higher rep or the author can add this for the community.

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer doesn't work for me anymore (R version 4.2.1). An option to fix this is by slightly modifying the function `coord_x_datetime` from the [`tidyquant`](https://business-science.github.io/tidyquant/reference/coord_x_date.html) package to reverse the datetime for your y-axis. Here is the function called `coord_y_datetime`:

```
coord_y_datetime <- function(xlim = NULL, ylim = NULL, expand = TRUE) {
  if (!is.null(ylim)) {
    ylim <- lubridate::as_datetime(ylim)
  }
  ggplot2::coord_cartesian(xlim = xlim, ylim = ylim, expand = expand)
}
```

Here is a reproducible example:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(MyData, aes(x = Value, y = Date)) +
  geom_point() + 
  coord_y_datetime(ylim = c(max(MyData$Date), min(MyData$Date)))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

As you can see the y-axis datetime is now reversed.

Comment: I had to change the lubridate::as_datetime(ylim) to lubridate::as_date(ylim) in order for mine to work (I was working with dates only not datetime). Apart from that, worked perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

A solution to this is using rev() should do the trick! ;)

In your case...

```
ggplot(MyData, aes(x=Value, y=rev(Date))) +
  geom_point()
```

Comment: It doesn't work. The Y axis data is still plot with dates increasing, and not decreasing, as was the original request.