# Advanced ggplot2 plotting, annotations with axis value of zero and dates

Tags: r, ggplot2, annotations, axis-labels

I'm almost very happy with my plot, made with ggplot2. However, I still have three last tasks left to do and I can't seem to solve them. I hope you guys and/or girls can help me out. I'm of course already happy if you could help me with one!

1. I want to reverse my months on the y-axis (actually the x-axis in my code). So from top Jan - Dec. I know `scale_x_reverse()` exists but it conflicts with `scale_x_datetime` in my ggplot code.
2. I would like to know how to create annotations but how do I do this without an x-axis (y-axis in code = 0) and with dates as coordinate data?

Is this where I reach the limit of ggplot2 and should thinking about learning D3.js? Or could some ggplot2 wizard show me the ropes? I hope so...

Here's a very little piece of my data frame:

```
candidate_bigrams <- structure(list(ID = c(6057L, 6059L, 6060L, 6060L, 6062L, 6062L, 
6065L, 6066L, 6074L, 6077L), created_at = structure(c(1513867942, 
1513860317, 1513859062, 1513859062, 1513780371, 1513780371, 1513696021, 
1513682620, 1513256396, 1513170172), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "US/Eastern"), retweets = c(6065L, 8848L, 12813L, 
12813L, 16629L, 16629L, 24577L, 13957L, 17226L, 29322L), favorites = c(22530L, 
41026L, 51936L, 51936L, 69592L, 69592L, 92444L, 65458L, 92117L, 
119570L), source = c("Twitter for iPhone", "Twitter for iPhone", 
"Twitter for iPhone", "Twitter for iPhone", "Twitter for iPhone", 
"Twitter for iPhone", "Twitter for iPhone", "Twitter for iPhone", 
"Twitter for iPhone", "Twitter for iPhone"), bigram = c("tax cuts", 
"fake news", "tax cuts", "fake news", "tax cuts", "fake news", 
"fake news", "tax cuts", "tax cuts", "fake news")), .Names = c("ID", 
"created_at", "retweets", "favorites", "source", "bigram"), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

and my `ggplot2` code:

```
library(tidyverse)

candidate_bigrams %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = created_at, y = 0, colour = bigram, size = retweets)) +
  geom_point(shape = 95,
             alpha = 0.7) +
  scale_size(range = c(1, 35)) +
  scale_x_datetime(date_labels = "%b", date_breaks = "1 month") +
  scale_colour_manual(values = plot_colours1) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        plot.background = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.y = element_line(colour = "#BDBDBD",
                                          linetype = "dotted"))
```

Every stripe is a tweet from Donald Trump, every colour is a specific 'bigram' or two-word-pair: "fake news", "tax cuts", and "north korea". My current end result with all the data:

[image]

Comment: Very interesting dataviz! Here's a tip how to reverse the datetime scale: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43625341/reverse-datetime-posixct-data-axis-in-ggplot/43626186. I am pretty sure it is still possible to do annotations, even when `y=0`. You can probably offset `yend` aestetic to be -1 and force the `ylim` to include annotations into the plot range. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your compliment and answer! Are you talking about setting `yend` and `ylim` in a `geom_text` function? Or `annotate`?

Comment: You will need to offset annotations away from the segments that will be connecting the label to the point you are annotating. For that you will use `annotate` and probably position labels with `xend` and `yend`. Yes, you also had a concern of how to indicate coordinates if one of them is date? Just use as.Date("2017-12-22") or something in `lubridate` to position your text on `x` axis. You will need `ylim()` or `scale_y_manual()` to make sure annotations fit onto the panel.