# Reversing axis of class date

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to reverse the y-axis of a plot. Now the column is of a class `date`. Numeric columns can be reversed by adding `scale_y_reverse()` or `scale_y_continuous(trans = "reverse)` but I can't seem to figure out how to get from top to bottom: `2005, 2006, 2007`. **I can't convert the date column to numeric** because I've annotations layers on months in my original plot.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- structure(list(date = structure(c(12784, 13149, 13514), class = "Date"), 
    nr = c(1.14192497730255, 0.719137012958527, 1.3783597946167
    )), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), .Names = c("date", "nr"))

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  date          nr
  <date>     <dbl>
1 2005-01-01 1.14 
2 2006-01-01 0.719
3 2007-01-01 1.38
```

Plot:

```
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(date, nr)) +
  geom_col() +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%Y",
               date_breaks = "1 years")
```

[image]

### Edit

I also can't [get this answer to work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43626186/5816847) because my column is of class `date` and not `POSIXct`:

`Error: Invalid input: time_trans works with objects of class POSIXct only`

Comment: https://gist.github.com/mikmart/bfbf62839fbdd162b4b88e6d43e0c858

Comment: ```df %>%
    ggplot(aes(as.numeric(date), nr)) +
    geom_col() +
    coord_flip() +
    scale_x_reverse(labels = as.character(lubridate::year(df$date)),
                    breaks = as.numeric(df$date))```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reverse datetime (POSIXct data) axis in ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43625341/reverse-datetime-posixct-data-axis-in-ggplot)

Comment: Could you add an example of the annotations you need to layer on? There might be workarounds that allow you to convert some aspects of the data

Answer (score -1):

You could create a new variable with the year as an integer:

```
library(lubridate)
df %>%
    mutate(Year = year(date)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(Year, nr)) +
    geom_col() +
    coord_flip() +
    scale_x_reverse()
```

Without lubridate, use `Year = as.numeric(format(date, "%Y"))`.

Comment: See my explanation why I can't change values to years.

Comment: The values are not changed in this solution, I added a temporary value to plot years. You can still use the date variable for other layers in the plot. This solution does meet the criteria in your question.