# Reverse datetime axis with custom breaks in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Reversing the date order is currently yet not supported in ggplot2, as stated in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/4014). A reverse datetime scale could be created by manually defining a trans function from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43626186/4550695).

Would be possible to manually define the 1. breaks and 2. labels of datetime axis, just like using the `date_breaks` and `date_labels` argument in `scale_x_date`/`scale_y_date` function?

#### Reprex

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

sample_data = data.frame(
  report_date = seq(as.Date("2021-01-01"), as.Date("2021-12-31"), by = "day"),
  report_var = seq(1, 365)
)

c_trans <- function(a, b, breaks = b$breaks, format = b$format) {
  a <- as.trans(a)
  b <- as.trans(b)

  name <- paste(a$name, b$name, sep = "-")

  trans <- function(x) a$trans(b$trans(x))
  inv <- function(x) b$inverse(a$inverse(x))

  trans_new(name, trans, inverse = inv, breaks = breaks, format = format)

}

rev_date <- c_trans("reverse", "date")


ggplot(sample_data, aes(x = report_var, y = report_date)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_continuous(trans = rev_date)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-06-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

#### Breaks

Manually define a numeric vector in **Date** class. Add it to the `breaks` argument of `scale_y_continuous` function.

```r
scale_y_continuous(
  trans = rev_date,
  breaks = seq.Date(as.Date("2021-01-01"), as.Date("2021-12-31"), by = "2 weeks")
)
```

[image]

#### Labels

Create a lambda function that takes the Date input and format the time. Add it to the `labels` argument of the `scale_y_continuous` function.

```
  scale_y_continuous(
    trans = rev_date,
    breaks = seq.Date(as.Date("2021-01-01"), as.Date("2021-12-31"), by = "2 weeks"),
    labels = ~ strftime(., "%b %d")
  )
```

[image]