# Reversing the y axis on discrete data

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a chart built with ggridges, as below, for which I would like to reverse the date order:

[image]

To do this I've added the c_trans() function, as defined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43625341/reverse-datetime-posixct-data-axis-in-ggplot#43626186), but it requires the day in posixct format, which appears to convert the date to a continuous scale, even when I define group as a factor:

```
  ggplot( lengthCounts2 %>% filter(rwi == rwiFilter), 
        aes( x = len, 
             fill = date,
             group= factor(date)
             )
        ) +
  stat_density( aes( weight = normalised, 
                     y = date, # time_trans works with objects of class POSIXct only
                     height = after_stat(density)
                     ), 
                geom = 'density_ridges', 
                position = 'identity',
                adjust = 0.1
                ) +
  scale_y_continuous(trans  = rev_date) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme( plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5)
         ) +
  # scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Pastel1") +
  labs( title = glue("Sampled/normalised packet size distribution for rwi={rwiFilter} ({rwiText})\n"),
        x ="Length (bytes)", 
        y = "Date"
        )
```

So that I end up with [image] which is clearly not what I want.  Is there any way to reverse the y axis but keep it discrete?

```
Input data:

> lengthCounts2
# A tibble: 8,724 x 5
# Groups:   date, rwi [6]
   date                rwi     len       n normalised
   <dttm>              <chr> <dbl>   <int>      <dbl>
 1 2022-04-13 00:00:00 01       35     677  0.0000319
 2 2022-04-13 00:00:00 01       40 3113138  0.147    
 3 2022-04-13 00:00:00 01       41   15078  0.000710 
 4 2022-04-13 00:00:00 01       42    2077  0.0000978
 5 2022-04-13 00:00:00 01       43    2554  0.000120 
 6 2022-04-13 00:00:00 01       44   29190  0.00137  
 7 2022-04-13 00:00:00 01       45    2065  0.0000972
 8 2022-04-13 00:00:00 01       46    2054  0.0000967
 9 2022-04-13 00:00:00 01       47    2625  0.000124 
10 2022-04-13 00:00:00 01       48  146334  0.00689  
# ... with 8,714 more rows
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
ylim("20220427", "20220420", "20220413")
```