# R ggplot2 - how to reverse y-axis having dates

Tags: r, ggplot2, datefield

In continuation with the ask from @David, I'm unable to reverse the y-axis having date field.
I tried to reproduce the reprex - solution given by @Marcelo and @Oliver, but it is also throwing an error as below:

Error: Invalid input: time_trans works with objects of class POSIXct only

I have executed the same code as mentioned in the below link:

[Reverse datetime (POSIXct data) axis in ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43625341/reverse-datetime-posixct-data-axis-in-ggplot)

Can somebody help to understand why we get this error? or is it because of any version issues in my system??

ggplot2 version 3.4.0
R version 4.2.2

I tried the same code as below:

```
MyData <-
  structure(list(Date = structure(c(1492979809.99827, 1492602845.68722, 
  1493093428.90318, 1492605578.0691, 1492961342.65056, 1492771976.83545, 
  1493020588.88485, 1493057018.85104, 1492852011.23873, 1492855996.55059
  ), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), Value = c(4.52885504579172, 
  6.0024610790424, 8.96430060034618, 7.06435370026156, 5.08460514713079, 
  3.47828012891114, 6.29844291834161, 0.898315710946918, 1.44857675535604, 
  5.74641009094194)), .Names = c("Date", "Value"), row.names = c(NA, 
  -10L), class = "data.frame")

library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

c_trans <- function(a, b, breaks = b$breaks, format = b$format) {
  a <- as.trans(a)
  b <- as.trans(b)
  
  name <- paste(a$name, b$name, sep = "-")
  
  trans <- function(x) a$trans(b$trans(x))
  inv <- function(x) b$inverse(a$inverse(x))
  
  trans_new(name, trans, inverse = inv, breaks = breaks, format=format)

}

rev_date <- c_trans("reverse", "time")

ggplot(MyData, aes(x=Value, y=Date)) +
  geom_point() + 
  scale_y_continuous(trans = rev_date)
```

Getting the error as below

```
Error: Invalid input: time_trans works with objects of class POSIXct only
```

Comment: This answer (of said discussion) might work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74436045/20513099

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @I_O, but it did not work in my case somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I think creating a transformer is overkill here. You could simply make the date-time a numeric variable, and use `as.POSIXct` as a labelling function inside `scale_y_reverse`:

```r
ggplot(MyData, aes(Value, as.numeric(Date))) +
  geom_point() + 
  scale_y_reverse("Date", labels = ~as.POSIXct(.x, origin = "1970-01-01"),
                  breaks = as.numeric(seq(as.POSIXct("2017-04-19"), by = "day",
                                          length = 7)))
```

[image]